# How to know last log before event? R language

Tags: r

I have table like this(input):

```
user_id    event       timestamp
Rob        business    111111
Rob        business    222222
Mike       progress    111111
Mike       progress    222222
Rob        progress    000001
Mike       business    333333
Mike       progress    444444
Lee        progress    111111
Lee        progress    222222
```

`dput` of table:

```
dput(input)
structure(list(user_id = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Lee", "Mike", "Rob"), class = "factor"), 
    event = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("business", 
    "progress"), class = "factor"), timestamp = c(111111, 222222, 
    111111, 222222, 1, 333333, 444444, 111111, 222222)), .Names = c("user_id", 
"event", "timestamp"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to know last `progress` event before first `business` event happens (output):

```
    user_id    event       timestamp
    Mike       progress    222222
    Rob        progress    000001
```

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: I think you'll need to explain this better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[order(as.numeric(timestamp)), if(any(event == "business")) 
        .I[tail(which(cumsum(event == "business")==0),1)], user_id]$V1]   
#   user_id    event timestamp
#1:     Rob progress    000001
#2:    Mike progress    222222
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully get what you are trying to do. Using `which` you can get the indexes of all non-business events (your data is called `input`):

```
indexes <- which(input$event != "business")
```

Then you can filter this vector of indexes to only have non-business events up to the last business event:

```
indexes <- indexes[indexes < max(which(input$event == "business"))]
```

Looking at the remaining rows we have:

```
> input[indexes,]
  user_id    event timestamp
3    Mike progress    111111
4    Mike progress    222222
5     Rob progress         1
```